# Declare and Set not recognized syntax for my SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, xampp, declare

I am running an SQL server version: 5.1.44 using XAMPP. I've been looking through SQL tutorials that use the commands DECLARE and SET.

When I run

```
DECLARE @iVariable INT, @vVariable VARCHAR(100), @dDateTime DATETIME
SET @iVariable = 1
```

It responds

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @iVariable INT, @vVariable VARCHAR(100), @dDateTime DATETIME SET @iVari' at line 1
```

Can anyone shed any light on why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or MySQL? Your tag says MS but the error message says MySQL.

Comment: "that corresponds to your MySQL"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use MySQL as the above error is not related to SQL Server on any levels...
I also assume you don't want to create a Function or Stored Procedure but use some variables in a query window (kind of "immediate window").
In this case you don't need the "DECLARE" keyword (as this has to be used inside Stored Procedures -also has to be the very first command after the 'BEGIN' keyword-).
So you should be able to do this:

```
SET @iVariable = 1
```

or even this:

`SET @iVariable = 15;`

`SET @iVariable = "foo"`

Yes, I know what you think now (about variables and their type)... but it's MySQL, not SQL Server or Sybase ;)

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I'm still a little unclear about this Stored Procedures business. I'm executing these statements through the SQL command field in phpMyAdmin.